# Getting my background to appear in the live server

Tags: html, css

I cant get my background to open with the live server. I am not sure what I did wrong. I have attached both my index.html sheet and my style.css sheet. All that appears is a grey screen for my background instead of the image. I am going to put login information on top of the background thats why I used linear-gradient.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hero {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
    url(123.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Global Automation Timesheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="form-box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.hero {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('images/123.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Use apostrophes `''` in `url('123.jpg')`. Also be sure, that you correctly wrote image location.

Comment: This still does not fix the issue. I just tried it.

Comment: The image "123.jpg" is a green image with design

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. This `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('123.jpg');` was right. In what folder is the image?

Comment: It is in a folder I created in the explorer titled "images"

Comment: If foler `images` is in the same folder as `style.css`, then in `url` must be `url('images/123.jpg')`

Comment: That was it Tomas, thank you problem solved.

Comment: Happy to hear. Please mark my answer as helpful.